# Creating a table with Latex so that the cells are not aligned between different rows

Tags: tables

How can I create a table in Latex so that the cells in the last row are not aligned with the cells in the previous row?

The table should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TEX.SE community. Where is your work? This is not a site "just do this for me". You can use this tool https://www.tablesgenerator.com/.

Comment: @Mara You can make a table with twice as many columns and then merge together 2 or 3 cells as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that the 8 visible data columns should have equal widths and that the column dividers in the final row should be placed half way between the column dividers of the preceding rows. If that's the case, the following solution may be of interest.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array}    % for 'w' column type and '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\dfrac' macro
\usepackage{calc}     % help perform calculations on the fly
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\tabcolsep} % or some other length
\renewcommand\sb[1]{\textsubscript{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\mc[1]{% handy shortcut macro 
     \multicolumn{2}{wc{2\mylen+2\tabcolsep}|}{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt} % for a more open "look"

\begin{tabular}{| l | *{16}{wc{\mylen}} | }
   % 8 or 7 visible data columns, but 16 underlying, "structural" columns
\hline
Notes & \mc{C\sb{4}} & \mc{D\sb{4}} & \mc{E\sb{4}} & \mc{F\sb{4}} 
      & \mc{G\sb{4}} & \mc{A\sb{4}} & \mc{B\sb{4}} & \mc{C\sb{5}} \\
\hline 
Frequency based on C\sb{4} &
   \mc{1} & \mc{$\dfrac{9^{\mathstrut}}{8_{\mathstrut}}$} & 
   \mc{$\dfrac{5}{4}$} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{} & \mc{2} \\
\hline
Number of cents above C\sb{4} &
   \mc{0} & \mc{204} & \mc{386} & \mc{} & 
   \mc{}  & \mc{}    & \mc{} & \mc{1200} \\
\hline
Intervals between  &
   \multicolumn{3}{wc{3\mylen+4\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth}|}{204} &
   \mc{182} & \mc{112} & \mc{204} &
   \mc{182} & \mc{204} &
   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{112} \\
adjacent notes, in cents &
   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{M} &
   \mc{m} & \mc{s} & \mc{M} & \mc{m} & \mc{M} & 
   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{s} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just have enough columns to capture all the cell boundaries and then span as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\mm[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{l|*{8}{c}}
  aaaa & \mm{1} & \mm{2} & \mm{3}  & \mm{4} \\
  \hline
  bbbb & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{xxx} &\mm{yyy} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{zzz}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is using `c` so the column widths depend on the content, if you want fixed widths you could use `p{..}` or (array package) `wc{..}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\v}{\hfill\vline\hfill}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{8}{w{c}{1cm}|}}
\hline
Notes & C$_4$ & D$_4$ & E$_4$ & F$_4$ & G$_4$ & A$_4$ & B$_4$ & C$_5$ \\
\hline
Frequency based on C$_4$& $1$ & $\frac{9}{8}$ & $\frac{5}{4}$ & $\frac{4}{3}$ & $\frac{3}{2}$ &
$\frac{5}{3}$ & $\frac{15}{8}$ & $2$ \\
\hline
Number of cents above C$_4$& 0 & 204 & 386 & 498 & 702 & 884 & 1088 & 1200 \\
\hline
\makecell[l]{Intervals between\\ adjacent notes in cents}& 
\multicolumn{8}{c|}{ \hspace*{6mm}%
                     \makecell{204\\M}\v \makecell{182\\m}\v 
                     \makecell{112\\s}\v \makecell{204\\M}\v
                     \makecell{182\\m}\v \makecell{204\\M}\v 
                     \makecell{112\\s}\hspace*{6mm}%
                   } \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]